# Issues blocking specific traffic using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, firewall

Good afternoon. I'm new to Linux and using iptables, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes. I am using version 20.04.2 LTS of Ubuntu.

What I am trying to do is block all traffic on a device on my network, such that it can only connect to another device I specify. Here are the steps I took:

```
# define new chain to allow particular source
sudo iptables -N newchain
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j newchain
sudo iptables -A newchain -s 10.42.0/24 -p udp --dport 3074:3479 -m string --string 000000000E3B115 --algo bm -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A newchain -j DROP
```

I defined a new chain, then used that new chain to allow a particular source, then I used that new chain to block all other sources. The above commands had no effect on the device on my network. I thought maybe the order was wrong, that I must block all sources first, then allow a particular source (so switching the order of the statements above), but that had no desired effect either.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The string I chose is a unique string found in a UDP packet transmitted from another device over the internet, so the above commands should be restricting my connection to only that device with that packet information.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that packets don't go through *newchain*. It is like a program's subroutine that is never called. Either add a *jump* rule to the INPUT chain `-A INPUT -j newchain`, or don't bother with *newchain* and add the rules to INPUT directly.

Comment: I tried both suggestions you mentioned to no avail. I am perplexed why these commands have no effect on my device's connectivity. What else could I be missing?

Comment: Show your entire code, INPUT, *newchain* and whatever else (don't try to put it in a comment; add it to the question instead).

Comment: I added to the original question your suggestion. The way the commands are typed are exactly the order I inputted them into the terminal. I should also mention that I am doing this on a laptop connected to the internet via a lan cable and using a wifi hotspot so other device(s) connect to my laptop. The intention is to modify network traffic on a particular device connected to my laptop via WiFi hotspot

Comment: It could be that the packet is accepted in the INPUT chain before it has a chance to hit the jump rule. Sorry for giving you sloppy instructions. Try adding the jump rule to the *beginning* of the INPUT chain: `iptables -I INPUT -j newchain`. To see all INPUT rules, run `iptables -S` or, for a different format, `iptables -L`. To see all netfilter rules, `iptables-save`.

Comment: Okay, I did what you last suggested. This time, network traffic did change (I couldn't establish a connection online to anything), but I still cannot establish a connection to the device on the network with the unique UDP packet string.
I changed the order in the original post of how I input the commands. Let me know if there is anything I need to correct please.

Comment: Your comment is pretty garbled, but I understand that now you are successfully blocking unwanted traffic but are not successful getting desired traffic into the device. Is there a way you can trace traffic (Wireshark, tcpdump) to see what exactly goes over the wire?

Comment: I am using wireshark. It's more of a blanket block of everything currently. What I am trying to do is block unwanted traffic and only be able to connect to someone with a unique UDP packet string (similar to the original post).

Comment: Ahem. I had not seen it: You first add DROP to newchain, then the string rule. The packets are dropped before they are processed by the rule. Sorry, you need to delete the drop rule e.g. `sudo iptables -D newchain -j DROP`, then add it back at the end of newchain.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I changed the order of the commands in the original post. Is that the order how it should be entered in terminal?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what the order of the statements in the original post should be. Should I be putting the drop statement as the second statement or the fourth (last) statement? I appreciate any suggestions you give.

Comment: `-A` means "add to the end of a chain". Rules are applied from beginning to end. If you first add the DROP rule, then the ACCEPT rule, DROP is the second to last, and ACCEPT is the last rule. This means that a packet is processed by the DROP rule before it has a chance to be ACCEPTed. Therefore, ensure that DROP is at the end by adding it as the very last rule.

Comment: There's still something missing. I updated the original post and I put the DROP statement at the end, but It is still blocking everywhere. I'm sure I'm missing something or doing something wrong from my end.

Comment: I don't know what other rules are in your chains. `iptables -S INPUT` and `iptables -S newchain` would reveal them.

Comment: Only rules I have are: -N newchain, sudo iptables -A newchain -s 10.42.0/24 -p udp --dport 3074:3479 -m string --string 000000000E3B115 --algo bm -j ACCEPT, -A ps5 -j DROP