# how do I restrict my connection during matchmaking services to only connect to users with unique match strings found in udp packets using iptables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, port-forwarding

Good afternoon. I'm new to Linux and using iptables, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes. I am using version 20.04.2 LTS of Ubuntu, and using my laptop running Linux iptables to create a wifi hotspot for my other device to connect to.

What I am trying to do is block all peer to peer traffic on a device on my network, such that it can only connect to another device I specify and matchmaking services of the running application. Here are the steps I took:

```
# define new chain to allow particular source
sudo iptables -N newchain
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j newchain
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j newchain
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j newchain
sudo iptables -A newchain -s 10.42.0.0/24 -p udp --dport 3074:3479 -m string --string E3B115 --algo bm -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A newchain -j DROP
```

I defined a new chain, associated the default chain policies with my custom chain policy, then used that new chain to allow a particular source. I then used that new chain to block peer to peer traffic that does not contain the unique match string specified as "E3B115" in the UDP packet data, specified in the port range 3074:3479 (these ports are required to be open to allow the device to connect to matchmaking services on the running application).

The above commands appeared to block all traffic (instead of peer to peer only) on the device tethered to my laptop, leading me to believe perhaps I blocked matchmaking services for the application too.

I suppose what I am having trouble with is blocking peer to peer connections without blocking matchmaking services for the application the tethered device is running.

The intention is to only  connect to matchmaking services of the application, and the peer with the specified unique UDP packets string.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you certainly blocked is the DHCP, DNS and mDNS services, so a) the device connecting to your laptop's hotspot won't be getting an IP address and b) even if it had a valid IP lease from before, it has no access to hostname resolution services that would allow it to find any hosts by name. The application might be using a 169.254.*.* link-local IP address as the source IP of its packets, and it would have to be broadcasting (to 169.254.255.255, not to 10.42.0.255). Also any "do I have internet connectivity?" tests by the device OS are likely to fail, which might affect its behavior.

Comment: What's the difference with your previous question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650331/issues-blocking-specific-traffic-using-iptables